# Как правильно настроить конфигурацию трассировки в firebird v3.0

Tags: firebird

Подскажите плиз, как правильно настроить конфиг fbtrace таким образом, чтобы лог по базе данных хранился в каталоге с базой данных?

В версии 2.5 я писал конструкцию в имени файла лога "\0.log", таким образом лог располагался по пути с базой с именем "имябазы".log, сейчас в 3.0 такая конструкция выдает лог с именем .log в каталоге с программой.

Конфиг трассировки выглядит следующим образом (мог немного в синтаксисе напутать, так как писал на память):

```
database = %[\\/]*.(fdb|db|fbase)
{
 enabled = true
 log_filename = \0.log
}
```

PS: Есть ли где руководство по регулярным выражениям, используемых в качестве параметра database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в сервере firebird 3.0 
[Тема на форуме sql.ru](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1283296/fbtrace-protokolirovanie-zaprosov-v-log-vozle-fayla-s-bd)